# checkbox onclick even not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having issues getting an onclick event to fire off the "Elevation" checkboxes at the above URL.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="A" id="elevation_A" onclick="changeElevation(this.value);" />
```

This does not ever process the "changeElevation()" function.  Even if I just place an alert() in this event it does not trigger.

Comment: Is there any reason to use inline JS instead of using event listeners? Also, there is obviously an error in your JS code—your script ended unexpectedly. Always check your browser console for error messages.

Comment: You're missing a `}` in that function

Comment: debug your code in browser and go to `console` where you ll find `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`. kindly correct it and then check your output

Comment: Use `onchange` instead of `onclick` for checkbox fields

Comment: I've added in the missing } to the function, but it still does not fire.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in console other then a char encoding one.  The checkboxes still do not fire on either onclick or onchange.

Answer (score 1):

issue with the tag closing.below is the code snippet.

```
changeElevation=function(){
alert("test");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fp-chk').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked') == undefined)
        {
            $(this).attr('checked',"");
            $(this).removeAttr('unchecked');
            $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).attr('unchecked',"");
            $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });


$('#elevation_A').click(function(){


        changeElevation('A');

     });
   });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0f0m10pq/

Comment: Is it something to do with how I have my checkboxes setup in the HTML?   <div class="floorplan-option">
           <span class="fp-chk" unchecked><div>Elevation B</div></span>
           <input type="checkbox" value="B" id="elevation_B" onchange="changeElevation(this.value);" /> 
       </div>

Comment: Because I have this code setup in the same manner, and it never seems to fire changeElevation(), or even get into $('#elevation_A').click(function(){

Comment: no HTML tags nothing to do with this.Check for console if you are still finding any issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could try using `this.checked` and then run what you want from there.

```js
function myFunction(value) {
  var x = document.getElementById("x");
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (value == true) {
    demo.innerHTML = "Checked";
  } else {
    demo.innerHTML = "Unchecked";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="x" type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction(this.checked)" />
<div>Value: <b id="demo"></b></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got syntax issues, but...

Use an on handler like this, I think it's a lot more cleaner and reliable and better adaptable if you have lots of checkboxes (you could attach this to a class or element handler).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#elevation_A').on('change', function(){ 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){ 
            //checkbox is checked logic
         }
    }) 
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Web developer has the right approach although you can use `onChange` as others suggested.
Your `fp-chk` function is handling the onclick. And, setting the styling of your checked box. So your not ever running the Elevation function; as the input is inside the outer parent div that is being clicked.

You could move the `changeElevation();` function to be called inside the `fp-chk` function.

If you have more Elevation Plans you could use this as a general call to the change function, from with in the fp-chk function:
`changeElevation($(this).children('input').val())`

Or if it is just one plan you will show, you can use a conditional-Or operator like so:

```
if($(this).children('input').val() === 'A'){
   changeElevation('A')
}
```

You should also consider using a pure CSS approach for your checkbox, you will then separate your concerns, letting CSS handle the styling and Javascript handle the control of your page states. Label is your friend and is very good at handling checkbox styling for checked states of an input. See more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/). And, this will show you how to style the checkbox with an [image](http://codepen.io/jointmedias/pen/HqCJe).